# g.fillPolygon not updating location (Integer arrays not updating...?)

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jpanel, paint

I've come across a problem when trying to move a custom polygon around a JPanel with the mouse; the location for the polygon never updates, even on repaint:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Figure extends JPanel{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int nPoints = 17, x = 120, y = -60;
    int MouseX, MouseY;
    final static int SIZE = 400;
    public int[] xPoints = {x + 100, x + 85, x + 70, x + 55, x + 40, x + 55, x + 55, x + 40, x + 25, x + 55, x + 55, x + 85, x + 85, x + 115, x + 100, x + 85, x + 85};
    public int[] yPoints = {y + 375, y + 385, y + 340, y + 385, y + 375, y + 335, y + 200, y+ 240, y + 225, y + 185, y + 175, y + 175, y + 185, y + 220, y + 240, y + 200, y + 335, y + 375};
    List<Integer> xList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> yList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static final Figure m = new Figure();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Figure");
        frame.getContentPane().add(m);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(SIZE, SIZE);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        m.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    }

    public void mouseMovement(){
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
                if(((e.getX() >= xPoints[8] && e.getX() <= xPoints[13]) && (e.getY() >= yPoints[10] && e.getY() <= yPoints[1])) || ((e.getX() >= (x + 45) && e.getX() <= (x + 45 + SIZE / 8)) && (e.getY() >= (y + 102) && e.getY() <= (y + 102 + SIZE / (57 / 10))))){
                    x = e.getX() - 75;
                    y = e.getY() - 150;
                    repaint();
                }else{
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Figure(){
        mouseMovement();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, nPoints);
        g.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, nPoints);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillOval(x + 45, y + 102, SIZE / 8, SIZE / (57 / 10));
    }

}
```

My thoughts on this are that the integer array is not updating properly using my predefined variables, but then I come across the problem of not knowing how to properly update it. It seems like it should, considering the location for the oval i made to represent the figure's "head" does, but apparently I'm wrong on that, so I'd like to know why just using the array in `fillPolygon` doesn't work and how I'd get the location to update. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: A List is not an Array...

Comment: You don't ever change your points.

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl: I'm not using `xList` and `yList` yet, if that's what you're referring to. if your referring to the two `int[]`'s, I've come to understand that those are called arrays. Or am I wrong and should I edit that out?

Comment: @Radiodef: what do you mean? if you are referring to the variables x and y, those update fine because the oval location always updates correctly. If you are referring to me calling the `xPoints` and `yPoints` arrays for `fillPolygon`, your simply restating my question.

Comment: You have to do it yourself. : / Arrays don't update themselves. When you say `= { x + 100...` that isn't like declaring a function, it just performs addition and assigns the element. Changing `x` won't change the array. You have to recalculate them all each time.

Comment: @Radiodef: problem is, when I put in that statement for updating the array, as in `xPoints = {x + 100, etc.}` after the statement for updating the x and y variables in `mouseDragged`, I get a whole bunch of compilation errors.

Comment: `= { ... }` only works immediately after a declaration IE `int[] someArray = { ... };`. Otherwise you have to declare the `new` as in `someArray = new int[] { ... };`. It would be better to go through and assign each element individually though because then you don't instantiate a new object every time the coords change. Even better is what @camickr suggests, using a Polygon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Polygon` class to create a Polygon using your Array of points.

Then in the painting method you can cast the Graphics object to a Graphics2D object and use the `Graphics2D.fill(Shape)` method to paint the polygon.

When you need to move the Polygon you can use the `translate(...)` method of the Polygon class.

Also, you should NOT be overriding the paint() method. Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method.

Comment: how would I go about doing this? just `Graphics2D g2d = new Graphics2D();`?

Comment: `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();` is the 'proper' way. Then call `g2d.dispose();` at the end of `paintComponent`. Depending on what you are doing you can also just cast it as in `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;` (don't call dispose if you do it this way).

Comment: I'm assuming by 'proper' you mean conventional and works the best. And is it a problem if I'm just using `paint` and not `paintComponent`? It seems like either way it should work...

Comment: You create a new Graphics object when you change properties of the Graphics object by doing transforms and rotations and so on. If you just use the Graphics object to painting you don't need to create a copy.

Comment: `is it a problem if I'm just using paint and not paintComponent?` - The proper way is to override paintComponent(), that is why I took the time to mention it. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Comment: changed `paint` to `paintComponent`, change a few variables to work with `g2d.translate`, but still only the oval moves. Why?

Comment: @camickr is suggesting you use a `java.awt.Polygon` instead of `drawPolygon`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html You can translate the graphics but Polygon has its own translate method.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense XD because using g2d.fillPolygon the same thing as what I was already doing? I think this is just what I need to solve my problem. Thanks!